# How to set mainActivity unshown in release and shown in debug version automatically

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to set MainActivity unshown in release and shown in debug version automatically. I knew how to do in manifest file manually, but I want to do it automatically when compile and export debug or release version.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two different manifest files for debug and release, the way to achieve this is to put them under `src/release/` and `src/debug/` directories

Comment: any other way to solve it? Like use code to config it dynamically?

Comment: AFAIK scope of your requirement is above your code, but If you are not strict on your request, you may create a bridge activity set it as default and based on your state (`BuildConfig.DEBUG`) you can finish it and start your desired activity